# iOS - inserting dictionary in SKDatabase

Tags: sql, ios

I am using SKDatabase and using API's SKDatabase to access it.

I am able to insert a dictionary into table first time successfully, But second time onwards i am facing issue.

It is rewriting the first values again and again not allowing to write new values, When i am inserting multiple dictionaries through for loop.

Meanwhile, it is allowing a dictionary for other tables, which have been inserting a single dictionary for a table.

I am placing some code here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_contentArray count]; i++)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [_contentArray objectAtIndex:i];
                [[PBDB instance].db insertDictionary:dictionary forTable:@"Daily"];
                NSLog(@"%@",dictionary);
            }
```

It is printing correct values in Console, But in database it adds first time entered values only instead of original values.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Probably not the reason for your specific problem but you MUST NOT release `dictionary`. You only release objects that you got by sending a `alloc`, `new`, `retain` or `copy` message.

Comment: It is showing repeat values in database But when i am displaying those values, it displays correct values.   I din't understand why it is showing repeat values in database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you had forgotten to charge your db instance

```
[[PBDB instance] chargeWithFileName:@"dbname.sqlitedb"];
```

Answer (score 0):

download skdatabese file for ios sdk

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhw1x8mgyeatkvb/Skdatabase.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
* Create object in appdelegate.h

    sk=[[SKDatabase alloc]init];
    NSString *db=@"db_name.sqlite";
    [sk initWithDynamicFile:db];

#pragma mark *** insert data

 NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setObject:_txt_fname.text forKey:@"first_name"];
            [dict setObject:_txt_email.text forKey:@"email"];
            [app.sk insertDictionary:dict 
forTable:@"table_name"];//insert data into Database

#pragma mark :::Select Query

    NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select rowid,* from register_table"];
    arr_name=(NSMutableArray *)[app.sk lookupAllForSQL:queryString];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr_name);


#pragma mark *** Update data

    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dict setObject:_txt_fname.text forKey:@"first_name"];
        [dict setObject:_txt_email.text forKey:@"email"];
        [app.sk updateDictionary:dict forTable:@"table_name" where:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rowid=%@",row_id]];
```